# Открытие Html в WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Этим кодом я создаю html страницу и открываю ее в браузере, на странице должна быть картинка, но ее нет, каким образом можно исправить проблему.Картинка в **xap**-файле есть.

```
string html = `"<html><body><img src=\"Maps/Lenina_0.png\"></body></html>"`;
myBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

зачем лишние апострофы (**'**) в коде:

`string html ='"<html><body><img src=\"Maps/Lenina_0.png\"></body></html>"';` ?

---

надо так : `string html ="<html><body><img src=\"Maps/Lenina_0.png\"></body></html>";`

---

или так: `string html ='<html><body><img src="Maps/Lenina_0.png"></body></html>';`